# Android Camera.Parameters.getZoomRatios() only returns 1 value

Tags: android, zooming, android-camera

I am trying to get all the zoom values supported for the camera and offer the user a slider to move between them.  The problem is I only get one value back from `Camera.Parameters.getZoomRatios()`. I am testing on HTC Sensation device with Android 2.3.4 (gingerbread)

```
final Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

if(parameters.isZoomSupported()) {
    // get all the zoom levels
    final List<Integer> zooms = parameters.getZoomRatios();
```

zooms is always `[100]` This is also waht what I am getting back from `parameters.getMaxZoom()`.

I've requested all relevant permissions in my android manifest and followed the instructions in the Camera API javadocs.

My native camera app on that device supports many zoom values. Any ideas on what may be the issue here?

Comment: Can you print the size of the list i.e. `zooms.size()`. If this value is `1`, then  only one zoom factor is supported, else you could iterate through the loop.

Comment: Iterating through the list could be achieved through `zooms.get(i)`. Have you tried this earlier?

Comment: zooms.size() is only one the only value is "100", which from what I understand is the "default" zoom.  See my comment below on Daniel's post.

Comment: @GameSalutes.. In your question, you mentioned that your native camera app supports many zoom values. Did you retrieve these values from the underlying `HAL` layer or are you implementing the zoom in software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zoom ratios are probably not what you are looking for. Your camera can zoom from 0 to whatever is returned from `getMaxZoom`. Try calling [`setZoom`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setZoom%28int%29) on values from 0 to 100 (you say that is being returned from `getMaxZoom`), and see if that works.

Your slider could instead go from 0 to whatever is returned from `getMaxZoom`. As with many camera parameters on android, zoom ratios may not always be so trustworthy from every different vendor.

According to the documentation, the valid range for `setZoom` is 0 to getMaxZoom(). I have had mixed results with zoom working perfectly on all devices, but have just tested this on an HTC Sensation running 4.0.3. For `getMaxZoom()` I get 5 as the resulting int, and setting zoom from 0-5 works to zoom the camera. Your issue may stem from some issues the device may have had with Gingerbread, because when I print the zoomratios array I get the following:

> [100, 114, 131, 151, 174, 200]

**The zoom ratios array is meant to understand the factor by which each zoom level will zoom your image from a baseline of 1.0x zoom** (multiplied by 100). In the above example a setting the zoom to 2 would give zoom to the third zoom ratio bucket: a 1.31x magnification. This also shows why the first value is 100 -- because the first zoom value of 0 is equivalent to a 1.0x zoom.

It seems as though zoom is totally wonky on your device if you are getting 100 returned from the max zoom query. I would recommend throwing a try-catch around your `setParameters` call if this is the case to guard for manufacturer error.

Comment: I believe the query for zoom ratios is correct. Please check this link: http://androidxref.com/2.3.6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/hardware/Camera.java#2276

Comment: I gave this a try but unfortunately the call to 'Camera.setParameters' through an exception when setting arbitrary zoom values between min and max.  I think I am supposed to only use those that are in the returned zoom ratio list.  Is it possible that these only return hardware zoom values and that my android device camera is actually implementing a software zoom instead?  I am having other people test this as well so I will see if the zoom shows up correctly on their devices.

Comment: see my updated answer. The zoom ratios list is really meant to be a reference to understand the zoom values from 0 to `getMaxZoom()`

Comment: Makes sense from the documentation.  I have added a try-catch around it and it seems to always fail.  I have another test device I will soon gain access to that I will try again with.